# What's the meaning of BGP prefix?

Tags: ip, prefix, bgp

Through this website [IP to ASN lookup](http://asn.cymru.com/cgi-bin/whois.cgi),I can get a series of results about the ASN,but I can't find the meaning of BGP prefix.Maybe I know what it is,however,how it works?

Is there anyone who can tell me the role BGP prefix plays in the ASN system?

Comment: [Network Engineering Stack Exchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 7):

A prefix announced in [BGP](https://noction.com/intelligent-routing-platform-bgp-network-optimization) consists of the IPv4 or IPv6 address block being announced and also a path of AS numbers, indicating which ASNs the traffic must pass through to reach the announced address block.

A BGP prefix would look something like (IPv4): 701 1239 42 206.24.14.0/24. The /24 part is referred to as a CIDR mask. The /24 indicates that the first 24 bits in the address block is the ?network? part of the address block.

Robtex provides BGP prefixes for each AS number (ex. https://www.robtex.com/as/as42.html#bgp)

Answer (score 6):

First, let us clarify the relationship among an IP prefix, a route, and BGP NLRI.

The primary function of BGP protocol is to exchange network reachability information (i.e. routes) between BGP speakers. Routes are advertised between BGP peers in BGP update messages.

A route contains 1) a set of destinations as an IP prefix which is carried in the Network Layer Reachability Information (NLRI) field in a [BGP update message](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4271#section-4.3), and 2) the attributes of the path to the destinations, which is carried in the path attributes field in a BGP update message.

Specifically, in BGP update message, an IP prefix is encoded as a 2-tuple form (length, prefix). Also, BGP has an AS_PATH path attribute which is a list of AS numbers through which the routes in this BGP update message has passed. For more details about how AS_PATH works, you can refer to [RFC4271 section 5.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4271#section-5.1.2).

And of course, a BGP session (eBGP or iBGP) needs to be successfully established in order to exchange BGP update messages.

So now we can summary the answer for your question, a prefix is a part of a BGP route, and will be exchanged between BGP neighbors in a BGP update message.

Answer (score 0):

BGP protocol is responsible to exchange IP blocks advertisement (IP prefixes) between Autonomous Systems.

So when you run a query on Cymru IP tool what you see is the IP blocks advertised on Internet using BGP protocol **as they reach Cymru routers**. In other words this is the internet routing table from their perspective.

Tools like this has a name: looking glass. There's a lot of LG's on globe as they're a very nice tool to understand how IP blocks spread around Internet. BGP play is another project that uses some LG's to mount a graphic view from the Internet prefixes. Check it: https://stat.ripe.net/bgplay

Answer (score 0):

In BGP, a set of destinations is advertised as an IP prefix, eliminating the concept of network "class" within BGP.